# Relative elements overlap absolute ones in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-position

I have what seems like a simple arrangement: a list of tags in a UL, and the last list item holds an absolutely positioned list of the "rest" of the tags.

See a stripped down demo here: http://dev.timmurtaugh.com/demo/chrome-problem/browse-bar-sandbox.html

In Chrome (and only Chrome so far as I can tell; version 19.0.1084.56) the absolutely positioned list is being overlapped by the "Instrument" header below it.

Help!

Comment: http://imgur.com/fLGf1 - like that? Did this in Chrome 19 by setting `.seeMore` to `z-index: 2` and the `.browseBar h2.toggles` to `z-index: 1` - might have to tweak those to fit the rest of your z-index assignments, though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding z-index:999 to below mentioned class:

```
.browseBar ul.tagList li.seeMore, .browseBar ul.tagList li.clearAll {
  position: relative;
  color: #C82D09;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 999; /* Add This */
}
```

Comment: Ahhhh, I knew I was being an idiot somehow. The z-index of the PARENT. Thank you thank you!